# how to allow two async tasks while blocking each other but not the main thread

Tags: android, kotlin-coroutines

I have two async tasks that should not execute in parallel i.e. wait until the other one finished before starting.

I guess i can make a variable indicating one is in progress and block the other but i am looking for a more elegant solution

For testing i made two functions as bellow which i run at a `ViewModel` class from `MainActivity` `onCreate` one after the other

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate() {
        //..
        mainActivityViewModel.test1()
        mainActivityViewModel.test2()

        Log.d("testco", "MainActivity: after test")
    }
}


class MainActivityViewModel: ViewModel() {

   fun test1() {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            coroutineScope {
                Log.d("testco", "test1: start")
                Thread.sleep(4000)
                Log.d("testco", "test1: finished")
            }
        }

    }

    fun test2() {
        viewModelScope.launch  {
            coroutineScope {
                Log.d("testco", "test2: start")
                Thread.sleep(1000)
                Log.d("testco", "test2: finished")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It is working as required, showing the next log (note how `test2` does not start until `test1` completed)

> test1:start
>
> test1: finished
>
> test2: start
>
> test2: finished
>
> MainActivity: after test

But, it is blocking the main thread as you can see at the logs

How to get the same behavior in logs but without blocking the main thread?

ps: looking at the `Thread.sleep` code description it says

> Causes the currently executing thread to sleep...

So i guess it means it is doing what i expect which is to delay only the thread it is executing in. `delay` on the other does not block the thread.

Answer (score 0):

- Prefer to use `suspend function` because [Sequential by default](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/composing-suspending-functions.html#sequential-by-default).
- Should not use `Thread.sleep`, use `delay` instead.

```kotlin
suspend fun task1() {
    delay(200) // pretend we are doing something useful here
    println("Task 1 done")
}

suspend fun task2() {
    delay(100) // pretend we are doing something useful here
    println("Task 2 done")
}

viewModelScope.launch {
    task1()
    task2()
    ...   
}
```

Comment: `test1` and `test2` are two separate async tasks. If i wanted to do them sequential , i could just write them in same `viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.Default)`. And i used the `sleep` since it was only for testing, to make sure they are blocking each other.